# Exiting Do While loop

Tags: c, loops, fgets, gets

I was working on some homework, and came across this issue.

> Write a program that reads several lines of text and prints a table indicating the number of one-letter words, two-letter words,
> three-letter words, and so on, appearing in the text.  For example the
> phrase "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer"
>
> Will contain
>
> 1 letter words: 0
>
> 2 letter words: 2
>
> 3 letter words: 1
>
> 4 letter words: 2 (including 'tis)
>
> 5 letter words: 0
>
> 6 letter words: 2
>
> 7 letter words: 1

My code for the question is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXDIMENSIONS 1000 //set max dimensions
#define MAXLENGTH 1000 //set max length

void separate(char stringArray[][MAXLENGTH], int words);
void printTable(char stringArray[][MAXLENGTH], int c);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    char txt[MAXLENGTH];
    char *token;
    char mat[MAXDIMENSIONS][MAXLENGTH];
    int i=0,wordcount=0;
    
    do{
        printf(">>>Write and press enter (EXIT for end of program)<<< : ",49);
        fgets(txt,sizeof txt,stdin);
        if(strcmp(txt,"EXIT")!=0)
        {
            token=strtok(txt," ");
            strcpy(mat[i],token);
            i++;
            while(token!=NULL){
                token=strtok(NULL, " ");
                if(token!=NULL){
                    strcpy(mat[i],token);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }while(strcmp(txt,"EXIT")!=0);
    
    separate(mat,i);
    
    printTable(mat,i);
    
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
} // end of main

void separate(char stringArray[][MAXLENGTH], int words){
    for(int i=0; i<words; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<strlen(stringArray[i]); j++){
            if((stringArray[i][j]<65 && stringArray[i][j]!=39) || (stringArray[i][j]>90 && stringArray[i][j]<97)|| stringArray[i][j]>122){
                for(int g=j; g<strlen(stringArray[i]); g++){
                    stringArray[i][g]=stringArray[i][g+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void printTable(char stringArray[][MAXLENGTH], int c){
    int max;
    int value=0,j;
    
    max=strlen(stringArray[0]);
    for(int i=1; i<c; i++){
        if(max<strlen(stringArray[i])){
            max=strlen(stringArray[i]);
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n***********WORD LENGTH READER***********\n");
    printf("| LENGTHS || VALUES | \n");
    for(j=1; j<=max; j++){
        for(int i=0; i<c; i++){
            if(strlen(stringArray[i])==j){
                value++;
            }
        }
        printf("|    %d    ||   %d    | \n",j,value);
        value=0; 
    }
    printf("\n****************************************\n");
}
```

My issue is getting out of the do while loop on line 17-33. It is my first time using `fgets` and I believe that this is probably what is causing the issue. I had written the code using `gets` and it works like that, but I know that gets is not supposed to be used due to its vulnerability.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `fgets` also reads the newline charcter, so the text read will not match your `TEXT`.

Comment: @user3121023 Yikes! That was embarrassing I didn't know it was that simple.. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thank you for explaining I see what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `fgets` also reads the newline, your exit condition will not be met because of the newline. You can either include the newline in your check, `"EXIT\n"` or you can patch out the newline after fgets.

The following example also makes the loop a bit simpler:

```
do {
    fgets(txt,sizeof txt,stdin);
    char *p= strrchr(txt,'\n'); if (p) *p= '\0';
    if(strcmp(txt,"EXIT")==0)
        break;
    //....
while(1);
```